# how to configure spring beans with null return in context xml file

Tags: java, spring

is there a way if we can convert below java bean in spring xml

```
@Bean(name = "tls")
public SslContextFactory getSslContextFactory() {
    return null;
}
```

i tried setting up like below

```
<bean id="tls" class="abc.SslContextFactory"/>
```

but it returns me an object with all the values set as null. However, above java bean works fine and returns null as expected. I tried setting up as below,

```
<bean id="tls" class="abc.SslContextFactory">
<null/>
</bean>
```

but it is syntactically wrong.

i am a newbie in spring and working on multiple experiments to understand more about spring. any suggestion is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply autowiring this bean somewhere, you can use like this -

```
@Autowired(required = false)
private SslContextFactory tls;
```

Also, you won't have to declare anything in xml. `@Autowired(required = false)` will set it to `null` if no bean definition is found.

Comment: how do i do that in context.xml. i was able to achive that in Java

Answer (score 0):

You need to use spring FactoryBean.

```
public class SslContextNullFactory  implements FactoryBean<Void> {

    public Void getObject() throws Exception {
        return null;
    }

    public Class<? extends Void> getObjectType() {
        return null;
    }

    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And

```
<bean id="tls" class = "abc.SslContextNullFactory" />
```